# libgdx - how to handle time-dependent events?

Tags: android, libgdx

I'm starting to develop a game in libgdx, and I'm wondering what the best practice is for the following situation. There are two things that I'm trying to do at the moment: move a menu (sprite) into place, and pan the camera to the player sprite. My idea to accomplish these things is to have an 'action_stack' ArrayList in the render() function. The ArrayList would contain 'Action' instances. Each `Action` instance would have a `step()` function, which would be over-ridden. In the `render()` function, I would iterate through `action_stack`, and fire each elements' `step()` function. So, to accomplish moving the menu into place, I would create the class:

```
public class MenuAnim1 implements Action {

    private int targetX;
    private int targetY;
    private Sprite menu;

    public MenuAnim1() {
        //set initial sprite and position
    }

    public Step() (
        //move this.menu towards targetX and targetY
            //draw the sprite
        //if not at target position, do nothing
        //if at target position, remove this object from action_stack
    }
}
```

...and put an instance into the `action_stack`:

```
MenuAnim1 menuAnim1 = new MenuAnim1();
action_stack.add(menuAnim1);
```

Sorry if my Java is bad, I'm not super familiar with it. Anyways, my question is: is this even good practice? What do people normally do? Is there a better way to do what I'm describing above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have never used [Action](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Action.html)s, but your idea is good. If you want them to be time dependant (and thus fps independant), be sure to use the time that has passed since the last frame to the current, also known as **delta** or **deltaTime**. You can get it like this:

```
Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
```

so, to make your action move the sprite, for example, to the right, this would do the trick:

```
speed = 10; //It will move 10 units per second.
delta = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
menu.translateX(speed*delta);
```

([Sprite#translateX](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Sprite.html#translateX%28float%29))

Comment: What is `.getDeltaTime()` relative to? The most recent call to `getDeltaTime()`?

Comment: Nop, its the time between the last call to [render](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/ApplicationListener.html#render%28%29) and the current one. (The last frame and the current)